# How to disable cache in Business Connector Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

When I try to get data from PriceDiscTable I get old data.
In this case I need to reconnect or disable cache in table properties (CacheLookup).

How can I get correct data without disabling CacheLookup property?

I tried

```
priceDiscTable.disableCache(true);
```

but problem still exist.

Comment: What build are you on and do you have multiple AOS? I seem to recall out-of-sync server cache in a load balanced environment with 2009.

Comment: Kernel 5.0.1500.4570
Application 5.0.1500.4570
Solution 5.0.1506.1087

Now only one AOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `priceDiscTable.reread()`. This will query the database to reread the record.

Answer (score 0):

I changed code to

```
priceDiscTable.disableCache(true);
priceDiscTable.reread();
```

I restarted AOS clear all caches and *.auc files

Now it works fine